# add_filter is failing to append &rel=0 to end of YouTube URL in oEmbed

Tags: embed, oembed, youtube

I'm working with a WordPress website owner who wants to only display their own videos in the "Related Videos" at the end of each embedded video. I've used Chrome Inspector to demonstrate that this will work by appending &rel=0 to the end of the embed URL.

Next, I wrote the following filter for WordPress to ensure that the URL gets written this way:

```
add_filter( 'embed_oembed_html', 'wpse_filter_oembed', 10, 4 );

function wpse_filter_oembed( $html, $url, $attr, $post_ID ) {

  if ( strpos( $html, 'youtube.com' ) !== false ) {

    $src = $attr['src'];
    $new_src = add_query_arg( 'rel', 0, $src );

    $html = str_replace( $src, $new_src, $html );

  }

  return $html;

}
```

But the code doesn't seem to do anything. It doesn't append &rel=0 to the end of the YouTube URL.

I've also tried various jQuery approaches, but everything I do gets ignored. What is the way to make this work every time for every YouTueb video on every page?

Comment: where is the code located? Note that youtube.com is not the only domain used for youtube embeds, if you look at the docs for that filter on the official WP developer portal the first example is for youtube and handles both major domains

Comment: My code above is in functions.php file of the theme. The jQuery code I also tried was in the <head> tag. The domain in all the embeds on the site is always youtube.com, never youtu.be.

Comment: it'd be good to eliminate, that instead of trusting that it shouldn't be an issue we can guarantee that it will _never_ be an issue. It might be that it always starts as youtube.com but gets converted. Also, these are standard OEmbeds, for fresh new youtube URLs? Not elementor/bakery/bricks youtube inserts or raw HTML embeds, or old cached youtube embeds? WP won't make HTTP requests to google every single time the content is rendered

Comment: Embeds are handled by Smash Balloon's Youtube Feeds plugin. When I embed the videos with native YouTube I can manually append to the URL to get what I want. But the jQuery or functions.php filter doesn't work with native YT embeds either.

Comment: that's critical information that should be at the top of your question, does this problem go away when you disable that plugin? You can't ask for help with 3rd party plugins here and any answers you get will be for the native OEmbed implementation, but that plugin could be replacing the default implementation or interfering in other ways that break. You might even find your original code is correct but needs to be changed in a way that's specific to that plugin. At a minimum it should be disabled as well as any other youtube related plugins while you debug this issue and try to find an answer